# F? (f.e. F8) shortcuts not working in geany

Tags: shortcut-keys, geany

I'd like to ask for tips why shortucts f.e. for build <kbd>F9</kbd> or compile <kbd>F8</kbd> are not working in Geany text editor.

I tried to assign different shortcuts including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and none of them worked.

Comment: Have you got multimedia keys enabled in the BIOS? Check if CTRL+ALT+F2 takes you to the command line (ALT+F7 to get back.)

Comment: Yes, CTRL + ALT + F2 takes me to terminal.

Comment: Can you assure these are not cached by your operating system or desktop environment? Which system are you using? What were you trying to assign?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem? You never replied to the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I observe that this only happens after accidentally pressing the shortcuts in the VTE (the embedded terminal). Even after switching focus back to the main editor, these shortcuts still do not work.

To fix, go to Edit -> Preferences -> Terminal, then uncheck the "Override Geany keybindings" option. However this will disable all keybindings for the terminal, including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for SIGINT. If you don't want that, you'll have to restart Geany everytime it doesn't work.

This bug has been filed [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/geany/bugs/1032/), but it was closed as "won't fix". It seems to be affecting Unity only, and to quote [Lex Trotman](https://sourceforge.net/p/geany/bugs/1032/#854f),

> This is a Unity bug and not something we can fix.

I reported this on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/geany/+bug/1318934).

Answer (score -1):

Some keyboards (like Microsoft's Digital Media Keyboard 3000) requires <kbd>Fn</kbd> lock to use the "<kbd>F*</kbd>" keys. Perhaps it is due to that.

Comment: I tried that, but it's not working. I have installed Ubuntu on my Acer notebook (so I have standard), NB keyboard. I do not use en keyboard layout, but I tried with that too, but still not working.

Answer (score -1):

It may help to make sure your source code files are named with the correct file extension.

I'm using the editor for Pascal, so in my case it helped to add the .pas extension to the file-/project name.